# Vertical center cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Why is not vertically centered the second column, while the first one it is?

```
\begin{table}[h!] \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.4\textwidth}| >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.54\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.4\textwidth}|}{\textbf{Tempo}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.54\textwidth}|}{\textbf{Effetto}} \\
        \hline
        $\left [ 10^{-13},10^{-6} \right ]$ secondi & ionizzazione e formazione di radicali liberi  \\[1ex]
        \hline
        qualche secondo-settimane & strutture cellulari modificate \\[1ex]
        \hline
        giorni/mesi/anni & tentativo di riparazione del danno; morte cellulare; mutazione cellulare \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\textit{Interazione radiazione e tessuti biologici}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example we can compile. Code fragments help in explanations, but they are not a good basis for presenting or solving problems. How can the first be vertically centred and the second not? What is the first centred with respect to exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of the added lengths `\\[1ex]`. You can replace this with the `cellspace` package, which defines *minimal* vertical spacings between a cell and the above and below cells for columns with specifier prefixed by the letter `S`. Also I simplified the code for the column heads using the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{1ex}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1ex}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!] \centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{m{0.4\textwidth}}| >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{m{0.54\textwidth}}|}
    \hline
    \thead{Tempo} & \thead{Effetto} \\
    \hline
    $\left [ 10^{-13},10^{-6} \right ]$ secondi & ionizzazione e formazione di radicali liberi  \\
    \hline
    qualche secondo-settimane & strutture cellulari modificate \\
    \hline
    giorni/mesi/anni & tentativo di riparazione del danno; morte cellulare; mutazione cellulare \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textit{Interazione radiazione e tessuti biologici}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]